# Make an arrow shape with responsive width and only CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design, border

I'm trying to make a container that has an upward arrow attached to it. I am familiar with the [border drawing trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work) and think that's a likely solution, but it only works for known sizes I think, since you have to specify border in em or px.

The shape I would like to make is this:

```
          .
         / \
        /   \
       /     \
      | flex  |
      |       |
```

Where the content area can flex to different sizes as a percentage of a parent container.

Here is the CSS, with the problem area flagged:

```
.metric {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    width: 50%;
    background: lawngreen;
}

.metric:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    border: 75px solid white; /* this fixed width is the problem */
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: 25px solid lawngreen;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C8XJW/2/

Do you guys know any way to pull this off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another posibility.

This one does the trick with gradient backgrounds. You need 2 of them, so that the diagonal is easily achieved:

Relevant CSS:

```
.metric:before, .metric:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    content: '';
    width: 50%;
    height: 25px;
}
.metric:before {
    left: 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, transparent 50%, lawngreen 50%);
}
.metric:after {
    right: 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(to left bottom, transparent 50%, lawngreen 50%);
}
```

## [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C8XJW/3/)

The differences with *Simple As Could Be* solution:

**Pro** Transparent corners (relevant if you have a background)

**Con** Worse browser support

Comment: Wow, that's really nice. I like that one

Comment: Since the overflow:hidden border solution depends on box-sizing:border-box, the compatibility is probably similar between our two solutions and the linear-gradient one degrades better.

Comment: It's the first time I get an accepted answer from a self-answered question .-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one great solution. Bascially, you make the arrow always centered, and bigger than you'd ever need it, but lop off the overflow.

Here's the JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nBAK9/4/

And here's the interesting code:

```
.metric:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px;            /* max expected width /2 */
  content: '';
  background: white;
  width: 500px;                   /* max expected width    */
  height: 0;
  border: 250px solid white;      /* max expected width /2 */
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 50px solid #cf6; /* This size adjusts the slope of the triangle */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can, I played with it found that since `em` inherits from parents you can play a bit with it.

```
body{
    font-size: 3em;
}

div {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 3em 4em 7em;
    border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg)
}
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dTJsd/)

Comment: An interesting approach. What's the rotate 360 do?

Comment: @SimpleAsCouldBe it's supposed to improve anti-aliasing in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

```
.top-arrow:before, .top-arrow:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    content: '';
    width: 50%;
    height: 25px;
}
.top-arrow:before {
    left: 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, transparent 50%, black 50%);
}
.top-arrow:after {
    right: 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(to left bottom, transparent 50%, black 50%);
}


<div class="top-arrow"></div>
```

Comment: I made a fiddle for this, but I don't see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/7bun3xw0/1/